# How to nest a model inside a model in Django database

Tags: python, django

I have the following models, currently connected by ForeignKey:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

Is it possible to connect them in a way that in Django admin site I could go to a particular topic and have a list of all the entries displayed? Currently nothing gets displayed and I can only see the connection when I go to a particular entry (there is a dropdown saying to which topic current entry belongs).

EDIT: these are inlines added to the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from javascript.models import Topic, Entry

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(Entry)

#inlines

class EntryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry       

class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EntryInline]
```

Comment: Yes - use inlines. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed by using [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline)(TabularInline or StackedInline)

First of all create inline class for your entries:

```
class EntryInlines(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry
    # you can customize fields displayed here; make any field as read only if you want
```

Now include `EntryInlines` to the model where you want to display data (only if foreign Entry model has foreign key to respective model) as below:

```
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EntryInlines]  # you can add multiple inline tables too. pass it in the list
    # all other customization of your model admin if any
```

If you have nested foreign keys then you need to add this third-party-package like [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a legit answer, but I did as you wrote and also followed the documentation and still when I go to Topic on admin site the entries don't get displayed. I am putting both classes inside admin.py.

Comment: just to confirm are you hitting the `<model>/<id>/change` or `<model>`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, previewing models from shell? I am previewing  them through Django admin page.

Comment: I am asking from which url you are previewing it; you can see inlines only at change list view when hit url like : `/admin/topicModel/1/change/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168094/discussion-between-gahan-and-barciewicz).